# Permission Denied for SO_DEBUG socket option inside docker

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, docker

I've isolated the `Permission Denied` exception being thrown inside one of my test case to these lines -

```
...
ASSERT_EQ(0, getsockopt(s.getSocket(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, &optval, &optlen));
...
...
ASSERT_EQ(0, setsockopt(s.getSocket(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, &optval, optlen));
...
```

These work fine while running test executable with `sudo` on my local machine eg. `sudo ./test/testexe` and all test pass, no exception is thrown. To run these without `sudo`, I've tried setting capabilities prior to executing tests eg. `sudo setcap "cap_net_admin+ep cap_net_raw+ep" test/testexe` which again runs fine without `sudo` this time on my local machine.

The problem arises with docker where none of the methods work - neither `sudo` helps and exception is still thrown nor does the `setcap` method which successfully sets the capabilities but an error `Operation not permitted` is shown when executing tests.

So is there any other way of running `SO_DEBUG` lines successfully but without running docker with elevated privileges since I get control only inside the docker container with my CI platform.

Comment: did you try something like `docker run --cap-drop ALL --cap-add the_right_capapbility image`? so you drop all capabilities, and add only the needed one

Comment: @user2915097 as I stated that the docker container is setup by CI platform provider with default settings, eg `docker run -it ubuntu` so I only get control once I'm inside that container. However only `SO_DEBUG` refuses to work, every other `SOL_SOCKET` works fine, even `RAW` capability ones that require `setcap` explicitly.